# Criteria for a language (Terra as a tricky example) to be usable for operating system development, and how to meet missing criteria

Tags: frameworks, operating-systems, assembly, virtual-machine, lua

For example, a language that I was looking at recently- Terra. You can address the question in the context of any language, I'm just most comfortable with Lua so I'm starting from there.

The [Terra Language](http://terralang.org/) can be metaprogrammed with Lua and is backwards compatible with C. C code can be used inside of it and its code can be used inside of C. I'll give some code examples from the main page.

```
terra hello(argc : int, argv : &rawstring)
    -- Here we call a C function from Terra
    C.printf("Hello, Terra!\n")
    return 0
end

-- You can call Terra functions directly from Lua, they are JIT compiled 
-- using LLVM to create machine code
hello(0,nil)

hello:disas()
--[[ output:
    assembly for function at address 0x60e6010
    0x60e6010(+0):      push    rax
    0x60e6011(+1):      movabs  rdi, 102129664
    0x60e601b(+11):     movabs  rax, 140735712154681
    0x60e6025(+21):     call    rax
    0x60e6027(+23):     xor eax, eax
    0x60e6029(+25):     pop rdx
    0x60e602a(+26):     ret
]]
```

> Save Terra code to an external representation such as an object file, or executable. filetype can be one of "object" (an object file *.o), "asm" (an assembly file *.s), "bitcode" (LLVM bitcode *.bc), "llvmir" (LLVM textual IR *.ll), or "executable" (no extension).

Now, what I want to know (in relation to Terra and/or in general):

- Does this mean that I can write an operating system in Lua? (Is this the level of criteria I should be looking for when examing frameworks and languages?)
- If so, can I also implement Lua libraries such as Torch? (All languages have libraries, so I'm curious about what defines how much they can make use of them through OS development).
- Is there an objectively better way or language to do this? (As in, when does a language fully meet the critera yet not hold viability when it comes to operating system development?)

Comment: The question in your title and the questions in the question text don't seem to match up.

Comment: @immibis The question in the title is more general and the details in the body are more specific. It's setting a range of scope. I should have specified it more as an example of what I'm talking about, sorry. My mind is fragmented.

(Off-topic: Aren't you a Minecraft modder? The operating system's written on ComputerCraft's computers are somewhat an inspiration for my train of thought.)

Comment: The ultimate criterion that must be met for a language to be usable for operating system development is that someone must be able to write an operating system in it. If nobody's tried writing an operating system in Terra before, then you could always find out.

Comment: @immibis I found something called [eLua](http://www.eluaproject.net/overview), that you can boot straight into and run on the "bare metal". It's for embedded systems and has a few operating system features built in "like different File Systems, a command Shell, a remote console for Terminal access, ...". You can also upload Lua files via FTP and run them straight on the board, as well as running them through the file system.

I'm just going to hazard a guess and say that this is what I'm looking for, but I might need a bit more of an explanation (also on using other Lua libraries/Terra).

Comment: @ZacharyJohnson: But how is that the OS? What is *executing* the Lua script is fulfilling the services of the OS, not Lua code itself. You say it can do FTP. Well, do you think they wrote that FTP socket in Lua? It can access files, but is the stuff that actually talks to the hardware and deals with interrupts written in Lua? And so forth. eLua is merely a small OS that offloads the thinking part to a Lua script. But the OS part that defines the system is not written in Lua.

Comment: If you are just learning about writing an operating system, you might want to keep with high level languages, and write a virtual operating system (one running within the operating system), using virtual devices, etc. It will be much easier to debug.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well ALL software has assembly at its base, so you could argue that anything and everything you see on a computer is "written" in assembly. I tried answering my own second question, "How to meet missing criteria", and was too dumb to state that. I guess, more accurately, eLua is supposedly a Lua _interface_ to the hardware, and that is the kind of thing I am looking for. And the Terra language is metaprogrammed by Lua and can be saved as assembly code, so you could technically access the hardware through Lua that way as well.

Comment: @FrankHileman That was actually along the lines of my original question until I found the answer [here](http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html) and rewrote it as this one. And if you're using a virtual machine with virtual devices, why does the language being used matter?

Comment: @ZacharyJohnson for operating systems in particular, it doesn't matter, except for the beneficial side effects. For example, SeL4 is written in a sub-set of C that enables it to be formally verified, as well as compiled down to machine code.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand and define precisely what *exactly* is an [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). And the definition is not that simple, and is ambiguous in the details. I suggest to spend days to read [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Keep in mind that the definition of an OS may vary. For some people, it is what is installed in a (consumer) computer when you buy it brand new. For other people, it could be just the operating system [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29) (but they recognize that a kernel alone is completely useless: you need some [user space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) programs and some [application software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software)). Read also about [unikernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unikernel) (such as [MirageOS](https://mirage.io/)) and about projects like [Singularity OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29) or [Safe](http://www.crash-safe.org/). Of course read about [microkernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) & [monolithic kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel). The [OSDev](http://osdev.org/) wiki has useful information. The [tunes.org](http://tunes.org/) site is archiving interesting discussions (from the previous century) related to OS design.

Notice also that Terra is *not* Lua. It is a semantically C-like language which uses Lua for [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming).

> Does this mean that I can write an operating system in Lua?

You won't write *all* your OS in Lua (or in Terra). Likewise, those coding an OS in C (which is the case for most OSes today) don't code *all* the OS in C (some parts need to be coded in assembler).

Your question is ambiguous: do you want a language with which *most* of the OS can be coded (but then you need to code missing parts otherwise, perhaps in assembler), or do your require a language with which *all* the OS will be coded?

Low level things (scheduler, MMU and virtual space management, interrupt handling, hardware related stuff) are difficult (and probably impossible) to code "portably" in a pure high-level programming language. Because details matter.

See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/343797/40065) answer to a relevant and related question (but not the same one).

Comment: I define an operating system as whatever is on the machine right now. Just to add one more way to define it.

Answer (score 2):

Er, it depends.

Operating Systems can be written in any language.   [JavaOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS) was written almost entirely in Java as a bet, ran slowly, and then had to be sold as a product.  Most requirements, like performance, matter less than one expects because low level assembly or C code are dealing with the innermost loops.  Real speed-ups, like a smarter scheduler or LRU cache, can be coded anywhere.

Some languages, like Python, make terrible choices because the large virtual machine architecture requires a slow start up time. Some are tightly tied to ideal architectures and can't deal with GPUs, managing layers of cache, etc.   Some ideas are [improvements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH9VCN6UkyQ) in the small area.   There are a lot of languages.

Importantly, making your own language is common.  In Silicon Valley, there is at least one MeetUp where people design languages, usually compiling with [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) or the like.   In my opinion, start by writing a list of principles equivalent to the ["Zen of Python"](https://www.python.org/doc/humor/#the-zen-of-python).  Contemplate how your language will be a major improvement over all others.

Go forth and code.